# Getting OBS settings right for my setup

Tags: 14.04, youtube, video-streaming

I'm getting set up to do some live streaming and I'd love to get my settings and configuration sorted. I've got a Logitech c920 HD webcam, and a Thinkpad X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm trying to get a good hold of what settings to change in OBS to get a quality stream going. It's very very very choppy right now, even though in other programs (cheese) the preview is really smooth.

Any help would rock!

Also, I'm streaming on Youtube.

Comment: Here are the settings I use for good quality streaming:

Set FPS to 30,
Enable CFR for compatibility with streaming services,
Enable CBR for improved stream stability,
Recommended max bitrate: 3500,
Recommended buffer size: 3500.